# Smallest MongoDB Index on single character string

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

How do I make the smallest mongodb index on a field that's just one character (number) long?

I've tried storing it as an int which becomes larger than a string since mongo is using 32 bit precision. The ObjectID type is smaller than a single character string, but it looses the ease of use since I cant easily convert the number 1 to an ObjectID (Unless I do something janky like ObjectId('000000000001')).

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OID is a 12-byte type (https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/object-id/).

Int32 is a 4-byte type.

String is UTF-8 encoded (i.e - anywhere between 1-4 bytes), given an ASCII character it would be 1-byte only.

If size is the leading factor, I think string is the way to go in your case.